# mi pregunta es sobre laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

estoy usando laravel 9 y estas librerias

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#miTabla").DataTable();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- DataTables JS -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
<div id="miTabla"></div>
```

pero las palabras me salen en ingles y las quiero en español palabras como search, entries,Showing 1 to 1 of 1 entries que puedo hacer?

Comment: Buen día, yo te recomendaría leer la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/localization) antes de publicar una pregunta. El título debe ser significativo. [Lectura recomendada](https://normasapa.in/)

Answer (score 0):

Hay dos formas de hacerlo: la primera es inicializar DataTables incluyendo la definición del lenguaje:

```
language: {
    url: 'dataTables.español.json',
}
```

Y, por supuesto, debes indicar la ruta al archivo con las cadenas traducidas.
La segunda forma es incluir en la inicialización todas las cadenas que necesitas:

```
    language: {
        processing: "Procesando...",
        search: "Buscar:",
        lengthMenu: "Mostrar _MENU_ resultados por p&aacute;gina",
        info: "Mostrando resultados _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ encontrados",
        infoEmpty: "No se encontraron elementos",
        infoFiltered: "(filtrados de _MAX_ elementos en total)",
        infoPostFix: "",
        loadingRecords: "Por favor espere...",
        zeroRecords: "No hay elementos para mostrar",
        emptyTable: "No hay datos disponibles en la tabla.",
        paginate: {
            first: "Primero",
            previous: "Anterior",
            next: "Siguiente",
            last: "Ultimo"
        },
        "buttons": {
            "collection": "Colección",
            "colvis": "Ver",
            "colvisRestore": "Ver todas",
            "copy": "Copiar",
            "copyKeys": "Presione ctrl o u2318 + C para copiar los datos de la tabla al portapapeles del sistema. <br \/> <br \/> Para cancelar, haga clic en este mensaje o presione escape.",
            "copySuccess": {
                "1": "Copiada 1 fila al portapapeles",
                "_": "Copiadas %d fila al portapapeles"
            },
            "copyTitle": "Copiar al portapapeles",
            "csv": "CSV",
            "excel": "Excel",
            "pageLength": {
                "-1": "Mostrar todas las filas",
                "_": "Mostrar %d filas"
            },
            "pdf": "PDF",
            "print": "Imprimir",
            "createState": "Crear Estado",
            "removeAllStates": "Borrar Todos los Estados",
            "removeState": "Borrar Estado",
            "renameState": "Renombrar Estado",
            "savedStates": "Guardar Estado",
            "stateRestore": "Restaurar Estado",
            "updateState": "Actualizar Estado"
        },
```

Puedes encontrar la información que necesitas en https://datatables.net/plug-ins/i18n/